# Visual Studio Can't Update .NET

Tags: c#, .net, http, webclient

I have a problem in updating the .NET framework of a file.... I would like to use WebClient, but it's not available in .NET 4.0:

[image]

Comment: Try changing your target assembly [How to: Target a Version of the .NET Framework](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398202.aspx)

Comment: I can't see any questions. You just telling a fact: `webapi.client 5.2` is not available for 4.0 .NET and error is telling you that. What to do? Change your project to use 4.5 .NET as it is required. Or try to use old version of webapi which it might work on 4.0 .NET